# PostgreSQL: Check if substring is in a string and if true then replace the entire string with the substring

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column in a table like this:

---

```
|  biz_name   |
---------------
| www.Dog.com | 
| Dog LLC.    |
| Dog Inc.    |
| www.Cat.com |
| Cat Corp    |
```

And for each element in the column, I want to check if it contains the substring 'Dog' or 'Cat' and if it does, then to replace the entire string with either 'Dog' or 'Cat'.

The results should be:

---

```
| biz_name |
---------------
| Dog | 
| Dog |
| Dog |
| Cat |
| Cat |
```

Is there a way to do this without using CASE WHEN as such:

```
    CASE 
    WHEN biz_name ilike '%Dog%' THEN 'Dog'
    WHEN biz_name ilike '%Cat%' THEN 'Cat'
    ELSE biz_name END as biz_name
```

The above table is just an example to demonstrate what I'm trying to do, but the actual table I'm working on has many more substrings I'm trying to search for and replace with that using multiple CASE WHEN statements can get tedious. Does anyone have a more efficient way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Either way you are going to need to enumerate your Dog.. Cat.. somewhere so I think your approach is actually the most simple.
You could avoid repeating Dog twice by using regexp_replace instead, and replacing with the the found "tokens" but that's no big deal I think.

Comment: another solution is do an update `update [tableName] set biz_name = 'Dog' where biz_name like '%dog%'`

Comment: `with subs(s) as (values('Dog'),('Cat')), test(biz_name) as (values('www.dog.com'),('www.cat.com'),('dog Inc.')) select * from test left join subs on (test.biz_name ~* subs.s);`

Answer (score 0):

1) can you do a quick insert into a temp table

```
--assuming table name is biz

declare @name varchar(max)
declare @TEMP table (Name varchar(max))

-- insert all your values
insert into @TEMP values ('dog')
insert into @TEMP values ('cat')


set @name = select top 1 name from @TEMP
delete from @temp where name = @name -- remove from que /table

WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

 update dbo.biz 
  set biz_name = @name 
 where biz_name like '%' + @name '%'

 set @name = select top 1 name from @TEMP
 delete from @TEMP where name = @name
END
```

Comment: this is a solution done is MSSQL i'm not 100 sure if it translates to postgreSQL you might need to replace **varchar** with just **text**

Comment: every single line (but commented) from your script will not work neither altogether nor separately in postgres - sorry :)

Comment: Haven't worked with it for over a couple of years but the general concept remains the same.